# Volume of snow in my city

Tags: volume

My town is 4.7 square miles. We're getting about 6 inches of snow. 
Since 1 mile is 63360 inches I multiply 63360 by 4.7 to get 297792 square inches
Then for volume I multiply by the depth of snow which is 6 to get 1,786,752 cubic inches of snow

Did I do this right?

NOTE: I know there are many other factors such as melted snow, wind, buildings etc... this is just a very basic estimate of the volume of snow on the ground.

Comment: no you did not do this right. You need to find, as a step, how many square inches are in a square mile. Another mistake is you multiply inches to feet: You need to convert to the same unit before you multiply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $length$ of $1$ mile is $63360$ inches. The $area$ of a square mile is $63360^2 = 4014489600$ square inches. Now you can incorporate the number of square miles in question $(4.7)$ and the depth of the snow to get your answer.

Comment: you beat me to it